# how to load different div's onto a same div on click event

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hello my page is as follows,

I need to load one div into div1 when click on "structure",
and if click on style i need to load another div into div 1.

how to do this thanks.

http://softno.com/div.png

Comment: If you don't add further information to your question (including whatever code you already have), it's hardly possible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this example

```
$(function(){
  $('#structure').click(function(){
      $('#div1').html($('<div>', {'text' : 'structure'}));
  });

  $('#style').click(function(){
      $('#div1').html($('<div>', {'text' : 'style'}));
  });
});
```

Update

```
$(function(){
  // load default div to div 1
  $('#div1').append($('#default'));

  $('#structure').click(function(){
      // load some div to div 1
      $('#div1').append($('#divForStructure'));
  });

  $('#style').click(function(){
      // load some div to div 1
      $('#div1').append($('#divForStyle'));
  });
});
```

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. your script is working fine but i need to load full div into the div1 not the texts... how to do that?
and i need to load default div to div 1 in the start..

Comment: Update for your purposes added

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you seek?

```
var structurediv = $("<div id="structurediv">");
var stylediv = $("<div id="stylediv">");

$("#structure").click(function(){
    $("#div1").empty();
    firstdiv.appendTo("#div1");
});

$("#style").click(function(){
    $("#div1").empty();
    seconddiv.appendTo("#div1");
});
```